# Cold observable collection with completion

Tags: c#, asynchronous, observablecollection, system.reactive

So maybe I am getting this observer pattern all wrong, but this is what I want. I have a method supposed to get some integers from a database. Looking like this:

```
IObservable<int> GetInts()
```

Each time he is done getting an integer, he should tell its subscribers via OnNext(), naturally. However, if an observer comes late to the party, he might have missed some of those calls. I still want him to know all the information, so when he subscribes the Observable should "fill him in" and tell him the information he missed ... and then continue to tell him when new stuff is added.

However, at some point the data base read will be over, and the method will know it. At that point he should call the OnComplete() on the subscribers. So basically what I want is a collection that tells some stuff to people. I haven't been able to find something that does something like this, so I would have to implement it. It could look something like:

```
class MyObservable:List<int>,IObservable<int>{
private bool completed;
private List<IObserver<int>> observers = new List<IObserver<int>>();

public bool Completed{
    get{return completed;}
    set{
        completed = value;
        if(completed == true){
            observers.ForEach(obs=>obs.OnCompleted());
        }
    }
}

public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> obs){
    observers.Add(obs);
    this.ForEach(n => obs.OnNext(n));
    if(Completed) obs.OnCompleted();
    return Disposable.Create(()=>observers.Remove(obs));
}

public void Add(int n){
    observers.ForEach(obs => obs.OnNext(n));
    base.Add(n);
}   
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Something like this already implemented in Rx? Or if I shouldn't be doing this at all, what would be my best alternative?

If this IS the way to go, what kind of things should I worry about? (e.g. concurrency .. etc).

Comment: Here's a general rule when working with Rx - if you ever find yourself implementing `IObservable<T>` or `IObserver<T>` then you are doing something very wrong. You should always use the built-in in Rx objects and operators. Never roll your own. It's fraught with danger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [`ReplaySubject<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211810%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). It remembers all the updates it has ever received. When an observer subscribes to it, the observer receives the history of the subject, followed by all new updates.

Try out this example:

```
var subject = new ReplaySubject<int>();
subject.Subscribe(n => Console.WriteLine("A: {0}", n));
subject.OnNext(1);
subject.OnNext(2);
subject.OnNext(3);
Console.ReadLine();
subject.Subscribe(n => Console.WriteLine("B: {0}", n));
Console.ReadLine();
subject.OnNext(4);
subject.OnNext(5);
```

You should get an interaction like the following:

```
A: 1
A: 2
A: 3
<Press Enter>
B: 1
B: 2
B: 3
<Press Enter>
A: 4
B: 4
A: 5
B: 5
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I needed. 
Do you know if this manages concurrency as well? What I want to know is if there is a risk of a subscriber of the ReplaySubject missing a value. (Somehow he was subscribing while at the same time a new int was added in the ReplaySubject).

Comment: @SantiagoCerónUribe By default, subjects do not synchronize.  Take a look at `Subject.Synchronize`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229816(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Except this seems like it's almost unusable.  Doesn't it cause huge memory issues?  Save everything ever emitted by an observable sounds like it's only useful in a few trivial edge cases.